# TOR ORPort Unreachable

Tags: relays, network-configuration

I've setup a middle relay on ubuntu (virtual machine) and a bridge on Windows. However, on both OS's I'm facing the same issue as mentioned in the title.

For bridge relay, I've opened the ports in the firewall but the issue stays the same. Similary, opened ORPort (443) for middle relay in Ubuntu using ufw command.

I've wasted so much time on this and I can't get these relays running. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the torrc file:

```
Nickname demorelay
ContactInfo tor(dot)relay(dot)cn2020(at)gmail(dot)com     
#logs
Log notice file /var/log/tor/log
Log debug file /var/log/tor/debug.log   
RelayBandwidthRate 1 MBits
RelayBandwidthBurst 1 MBits
AccountingStart month 1 00:00
AccountingMax 0 GB
DisableDebuggerAttachment 0
ControlPort 9051
CookieAuthentication 1   
ORPort 443 NoListen
ORPort 127.0.0.1:9090 NoAdvertise
ExitRelay 0
SOCKSPort 0
```

Here's the log file:

```
May 14 05:30:09.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 15% (handshake_done): Handshake with a relay done
May 14 05:30:09.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 75% (enough_dirinfo): Loaded enough directory info to build circuits
May 14 05:30:09.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90% (ap_handshake_done): Handshake finished with a relay to build circuits
May 14 05:30:09.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 95% (circuit_create): Establishing a Tor circuit
May 14 05:30:10.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100% (done): Done
May 14 05:30:10.000 [notice] Now checking whether ORPort x.x.x.x:443 is reachable... (this may take up to 20 minutes -- look for log messages indicating success)
May 14 05:31:29.000 [notice] Your network connection speed appears to have changed. Resetting timeout to 60s after 18 timeouts and 101 buildtimes.
May 14 05:50:07.000 [warn] Your server (x.x.x.x:443) has not managed to confirm that its ORPort is reachable. Relays do not publish descriptors until their ORPort and DirPort are reachable. Please check your firewalls, ports, address, /etc/hosts file, etc
```

Comment: Can you add more detail about your network setup? Is your computer behind NAT? How did you set up networking for your VM, and how did you set up forwarding to the VM? Are you sure you want to be listening on loopback and not all interfaces (0.0.0.0)? Also maybe try running a small web server on port 9090 in your VM and see if you can access it from the internet on port 443.

Comment: I have the same problem trying to run middle Relay. It bootstaps 100 %, but ORport is always unreachable. UFW on Ubuntu disabled. Perhaps any port forwarding neccesary on my router? I use Cisco EPC3925, but is says all ports open. Any help much appreciated. My Torrc file SocksPort 0 RunAsDaemon 1 DirPort 80 NoListen DirPort 0.0.0.0:22222 NoAdvertise ORPort 443 NoListen ORPort 127.0.0.1:9090 NoAdvertise ExitPolicy reject *:* ControlPort 9051 CookieAuthentication 1